# Android regex - credita card track

Tags: android, regex

I'm emplementing a card reader and I need to use regex in android. Following wikipedia the regex for track1 is:

```
^%([A-Z])([0-9]{1,19})\^([^\^]{2,26})\^([0-9]{4}|\^)([0-9]{3}|\^)([^\?]+)\?$
```

Tried here: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html with the following example:
%B6011898748579348^DOE/ JOHN              ^37829821000123456789?
and it worked but not in my aplication.

```
String re = "%([A-Z])([0-9]{1,19})\\^([^\\^]{2,26})\\^([0-9]{4}|\\^)([0-9]{3}|\\^)([^\\?]+)\\?";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re);
String teste = "%B6011898748579348^DOE/ JOHN              ^37829821000123456789?";
Matcher m = p.matcher(teste);
    Log.d(TAG,"1111: "+m.groupCount());
int i=0;
for(i=0;i<m.groupCount();i++){
    try{
        Log.d(TAG, "GROUP"+Integer.toString(i)+" - "+m.group(i));
    }catch (IllegalStateException e){
    Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
    }
}
```

Teste with ^ and $ and multiline but none worked :s
the result is always:

1111: 6
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No successful match so far
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suc...
...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `m.find()` first. Also you should iterate including last group. Try this way

```
...
if(m.find()){
    Log.d(TAG,"1111: " + m.groupCount());

    //change '<' into '<=' to include group 6
    for(int i=0; i<=m.groupCount(); i++){ 
        try{
            Log.d(TAG, "GROUP"+Integer.toString(i)+" - "+m.group(i));
        }catch (IllegalStateException e){
            Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```